# Add button to splash screen to start the Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am working on an iPad application in Objective C, and I am using `UISplitviewcontroller` as my initial view.

How to add a button to the splash screen, so the app start when the user click this button?

I tried to create the Button in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but wasn't able to add it to splash screen

Can you guide me please

Comment: Create one another viewcontroller and set that view as a initial view , and add button on that view

Comment: +1 for a question I had similar. Not a fan of people who -1 questions that have a legitimate claim as a good question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary controller with name splashViewController and add splash screen image as background for this and place a button top of image.Add this window as rootViewController in `application didFinishLaunching`. Replace splashViewController with main viewController once actions in splashViewController finished.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  splashViewController=[SplashViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SplashViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navController setViewControllers:@[splashViewController] animated:NO];
  self.window.rootViewController =self.navController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
-(void)loadMainViewController
{
   MainViewController *mainViewController=[MainViewController alloc]]initWihtNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
  [self.navController setViewControllers:@[mainViewController] animated:NO];
}
```